# mysql, select source value of min expression instead of the minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that says

```
select u, min(abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, d, '2018-12-07 23:00:00')))
from ...
group by u
```

however I do not want the minimum, I want the value d that is the input that yields the minimum value.

This is in mysql 5.7

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way may be `row_number()`:

```
select x.*
from (select . . .,
            row_number() over (partition by u order by min(abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, d, '2018-12-07 23:00:00')))
                              ) as seqnum
      from ...
      group by u
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It appears mysql 5 does not support that, should've specified the version.

Comment: Yes, row_number is version +8

Answer (score 0):

`Group by u` to get all the minimums and join to the table:

```
select t.u, t.d
from tablename t inner join (
  select u, min(abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, d, '2018-12-07 23:00:00'))) minimumd
  from tablename 
  group by u
) g 
on g.u = t.u and g.minimumd = abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t.d, '2018-12-07 23:00:00'))
```

Comment: @Strawberry if you use `HOUR` as unit then `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2019-02-01 00:00:00','2019-02-01 00:00:01');` will return 0, but if you use `SECOND` it will return 1. So it is important what unit is used.

Comment: That's quite true - I assumed that the OP actually wanted the minimum absolute difference between timestamps, but actually there's nothing in the question to confirm that assumption